# Angular CLI: Generate htaccess using base-href

Tags: angular, .htaccess, webpack, angular-cli

With Angular CLI the base href in index.html can be set on build, e.g. `ng --base-href /folder/someproject/`. This is very useful for automatic deployment processes.

But projects like this may require a .htaccess also setting a base like so: `RewriteRule ^(.*) /folder/someproject/index.html [NC,L]`

Is it possible (with Webpack?) to set the path within htaccess also by use of base-href?